# Is it possible to make a callback function in c++ return a value?

Tags: c++

I have a circle struct and a list to store circles:

```
struct circle
{
    float r;
    int id;
};
list<circle> circleList;
```

I'm using Tinyxml to parse an xml document with information about circles (radius and id) and store then in the list: (this is in the main function)

```
circle c;

for(TiXmlElement* e = objectTree; e != NULL; e = e->NextSiblingElement())
{
    c.r = atof(e->Attribute("r"));
    c.id = atoi(e->Attribute("id"));

    circleList.push_back(c);
}
```

It's working fine, I used for_each to print the values and it works, the circles are being stored in the list. But at some point in the code I need to get the radius of each circle. I tried to do this in the main function, just after the for loop which stores the circles in a list:

```
float radius = for_each(circleList.begin(), circleList.end(), returnRadius);
```

Here is the callback function:

```
float returnRadius(circle &data)
{
    return data.r;
}
```

But I'm getting a lot of errors, probably because of that line in which I create a value called radius and try to store the value returned by for_each in it, which is totally wrong, I know. But my intention is finding a way to get the values returned by the callback function returnRadius. Is there a way to do this?

When I try to do this:

```
float radius = for_each(circleList.begin(), circleList.end(), returnRadius);
```

I get these errors:

```
error: cannot convert ‘float (*)(circle&)’ to ‘float’ in initialization
float radius = for_each(circleList.begin(), circleList.end(), returnRadius);
```

Which I understand because I'm trying to make the for_each function return the radius, but what I really want (and don't know how to do) is for the callback function to return the radius, after all, it's the callback that's retrieving this information

Comment: Showing the errors would help.

Comment: What exactly do you want `for_each(circleList.begin(), circleList.end(), returnRadius);` to return since each circle has it's own radius?

Comment: @NathanOliver the radius of each circle... for_each iterates through the circles list and returnRadius returns each radius

Comment: @jaryl `for_each` returns **just once**. It calls `returnRadius` multiple times, but it (`for_each`) returns just once. So when you say you want `for_each` to return each circle that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @jaryl And what do you want to do with those?  Are you trying to build a list of the radii?

Comment: @RichardCritten but that's the thing. There are errors because I'm trying to make for_each return the radius, but what I really want is for the callback function to return the radius, but I don't know how to do that. Anyway, I updated the question with the errors

Comment: @bolov Exactly! I know it doesn't make sense to make for_each return each radius. The callback should do this, it's the one that's iterating through the circles, after all. My question is how to do this. How do I get the value returned by the callbak?

Comment: @jaryl you have 3 circles in the list. One has radius `10`, another has the radius `20` and the last one has the radius `40`. `float radius = for_each(...)`. What value do you expect the variable `radius` to have after executing this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say you're overcomplicating things.

```
for (const auto &it : circleList)
{
    // Do whatever you wand with `it.r` here.
}
```

Comment: To be honest here, I was only using for_each because I tried to iterate through the list, but I couldn't access the struct data and I got a lot of errors. But this worked. It's strange, because the syntax I used was very much like this one.

Comment: @jaryl: `for_each` is neat, but in reality, I've never found a use for it. A regular `for` loop is almost always better.

Answer (score 1):

```
float radius = for_each(circleList.begin(), circleList.end(), returnRadius);
```

`for_each` doesn't return anything. It called `returnRadius` for each value, and it's now done. Exactly what you told it to do. If you want to do more than simply call `returnRadius` for each, then you've lied to the compiler about what you want it to do for each item.

```
auto print_radius = [](const circle &data) {
    std::cout << returnRadius(data) << '\n';
};
std::for_each(circleList.begin(), circleList.end(), print_radius);
```

In general, I avoid `std::for_each`. It's super neat, but makes code confusing to read.

---

If you're playing around with `std::for_each`, it can also be interesting to learn about `boost::transform_iterator`. It goes something like this:

```
//make iterators that transform circles to radius' on the fly
auto first = boost::make_transform_iterator(circleList.begin(), returnRadius); 
auto last = boost::make_transform_iterator(circleList.end(), returnRadius);
//copy these radius' to cout.
std::copy(first, last, std::ostream_iterator(std::cout);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make a callback function in c++ return a value?

Your title is not much related to the question's body, but I am focusing on it, and understand [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) in a usual way.

It could depend upon your C++ version. I hope you use at least C++11, then you can have [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)-s and [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)

Here is how to get a list (actually `std::list<float>`) of areas using [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) (often called [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) in other programming languages) with a lambda expression:

```
 auto areaList = std::transform(circleList.begin(), circleList.end(),
                                [] (const circle&c) 
                                { return c.r*c.r*M_PI; });
```

<sup>(you should be able to adapt that to your TinyXML thing)</sup>

You should read a good C++11 [programming book](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/).

You could read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) and the [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) and [anonymous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) wikipages